# Pointer to a pointer to an array outputting a bad value?

Tags: c++

My code is outputting the value of 7339536 and it is driving me crazy!

When I put the array as size 8 the code gives me an output of 7339536, but if I change the array to the size of 9 it outputs the value correctly as 8.

```
#include <iostream>

int main () {
    int number[8];
    number[8]=8;
    int *a;
    int **b;
    a = &number[8];
    b = &a;

    std::cout<<**b;
    return 0;
}
```

Why is the value 7335936 and not 8? When I change the array size to 9 is correctly outputs 8 so I am confused.

Comment: The first element of an array is located at index 0. The last valid index of an N long array is N-1, not N.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure what you intended with `number[8]=8`, but this is wrong. There are only 8 elements in the array called `number`, and this attempts to set the ninth.

Everything after that is forfeit, including a similar attempt later to take the address of said element.

Remember that the name of the array is `number`, not `number[8]`; the brackets are part of its type (i.e. `int[8]`).

Yes it's confusing that we don't write `int[8] number;`. This is mainly for historical reasons, though [this hypothetical alternative would come with its own problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54622434/pointer-to-a-pointer-to-an-array-outputting-a-bad-value/54622439?noredirect=1#comment96038504_54622439)!

Comment: `int[8] number;` would not be any less confusing IMO.  `T[8]` is eight T's ... unless T is an array in which case it isn't  (`int[3][8]` is three `int[8]`s).  Unless you also want to write three `int[8]`s as `int[8][3]`, in which case the last element of `int[8][3] x` would be `x[2][7]`.   Now what about 3-D arrays?

Comment: @M.M Mmm, true; multidims ruin that idea.

Answer (score 1):

`int d[6]` has six elements. 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5. As C and C++ starts counting from `0` unlike `scala`; therefore no user defined `d[6]` exists. So when you're trying to access `d[6]` it is returning junk from the registers, since c-style pointers are pretty much lawless. In short, `type pointer[no_of_elems_declaration]` translates to `0 to no_of_elements_declaration - 1` elements of `type`.

Comment: _"it is returning junk from the registers"_ It may, it may not. C++ is an _abstraction_. Doing this has undefined behaviour and any further reasoning is void.

Comment: Your final statement is wrong too. First, an array is not a "`pointer`". Second, given `int array[3]` the array certainly has 3 elements, not 2.

Comment: Speaking of C++; please re-read your comment with this standard C++ pointer memory allocation. `__float128 *d = new __float128[22];` written specifically for AMD cpu registers, allocating 22*128 bytes.

Comment: There is nothing standard about that.